# Active Record and Ruby on Rails strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activerecord-relation

Hi I have two models which are related to each other through a third model. The two main models are `User` and `Club` which have a relation through the `Reservations` table. The `Reservation` model has a column called `active` which is a boolean. The relationship between `User` and `Club` is a `has_many` to `has_many` ,through `Reservation`

When a user makes a reservation in a club,  an entry is made in the reservation table and the field in the reservation `active` column is set to true. If the user makes another reservation at the same club, then the previous reservation should have the `active` column updated from `true` to `false`

Here is my code:

```
user = User.where(:email => params["user_email"]).first
club = Club.find(params["club_id"].to_i)

reservation = Reservation.new
reservation.club_id = club.id
reservation.user_id = user.id
reservation.active = true

user.reservations.where("club_id = ? AND active = ?", club.id, true).each do |res|
    puts res.id
    res.active = false
    res.save
end

reservation.save
```

Now the `user.reservations.where("club_id = ? AND active = ?", club.id, true)` query returns the correct entries. I update the value and save it again. However when I look in the database I still see `active` column has the value `true`.

What is even stranger is when I run the same command, which I used in my code, in the `rails console`, it returns the correct entries. When I modify the command a bit and try to find all the entries with column marked as `false` I also get the right entries. If I select an entry which should have `active` marked as `false`, and try this `reservation.active == false` this returns `false`, but when I run `user.reservations.where("club_id = ? AND active = ?", club.id, true)` the results does not contain the entry.

Can anyone explain why I am seeing such strange behaviour. Thanks in advance

*** UPDATE ***

Here is my schema

```
create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "club_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "active"
  end

create_table "clubs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "name"
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "email"
  end
```

Comment: The code you posted basically does this: create an active reservation - find that active reservation and set it inactive. You should only perform one of the two blocks...

Comment: also, can you post your schema?

Comment: @TheCha͢mp I am actually initializing an active reservation but before I save it, I mark all the other reservations with the same club_id and user_id as inactive, so I don't mark the one I am creating inactive since it has not been saved to the database yet, also updated with schema